# Check of two list have colliding element?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

Is there a way to check if one list collides with another? ex:

```
    bool hit=false;
    foreach(var s in list2)
    {
        if (list1.Contains(s))
        {
            hit = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hit)
    {
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check for any element that exists in two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584179/check-for-any-element-that-exists-in-two-collections)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

.NET has a number of set operations that work on enumerables, so you could take [the set intersection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) to find members in both lists. Use `Any()` to find out if the resulting sequence has any entries.

E.g.

```
if(list1.Intersect(list2).Any())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use linq

```
if (list1.Intersect(list2).Count() > 0) ...
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `Count()` may need to enumerate the entire sequence. Use `Any()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use Linq then `if(list1.Intersect(list2).Count > 0) {...collision...}`.