# .NET check if two IEnumerable<T> have the same elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing two collections for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality)

I need to verify if two `IEnumerable<T>` lists have the same elements, not necessarily in the same order.

I'm targetting .NET 3.5.

Here are the tests. The question is, how should `HasSameElements()` be implemented?

```
var l1 = new[]{1,2,3};
var l2 = new[]{3,1,2};

bool rez1 = l1.HasSameElements(l2);//should be true

var l3 = new[]{1,2,3,2};
var l4 = new[]{3,1,2,2};
bool rez2 = l3.HasSameElements(l4);//should be true

var l5 = new[]{1,2,3,2};
var l6 = new[]{1,2,3};
bool rez3 = l5.HasSameElements(l6);//should be false
```

Aditional notes:

- In the examples I'm using IEnumerable, but T could be anything. Should T necessarily implement `IComparable` ?
- Enumerable.SequenceEquals() by itself doesn't work, it expects the same order for the elements.
- Here's a template for `HasElements`:

[just some placeholder text as workaround for Markdown 'code formatting' bug]

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static bool HasElements(this IEnumerable<T> l1, IEnumerable<T> l2){
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality

Comment: @Mitch: Make this comment an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: The question is a duplicate, but much better answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682729/check-of-two-list-have-colliding-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just build a dictionary mapping each object to the number of times it appears in the sequence and then check that the resulting dictionaries are equal.

Here:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static bool HasSameElementsAs<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> first,
        IEnumerable<T> second
    ) {
        var firstMap = first
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
        var secondMap = second
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
        return 
            firstMap.Keys.All(x =>
                secondMap.Keys.Contains(x) && firstMap[x] == secondMap[x]
            ) &&
            secondMap.Keys.All(x =>
                firstMap.Keys.Contains(x) && secondMap[x] == firstMap[x]
            );
    }
}
```

Obviously the repeated code can be refactored out into helper methods but that would just muddle the idea here. You could get fancy and accept an `IEqualityComparer` for the `GroupBy` operation. Also, you should productionize the code by adding `null` guards and what not.

Comment: Interesting. Does GroupBy() have O(n) complexity?

Comment: @Cristi Diaconescu: Yes, it should be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 5):

Although Cristi's `Except`-based method is brobably better, you could probably get away with:

```
source.Sort().SequenceEqual(target.Sort());
```

If it's for unit tests, I wouldn't be worried about the performance. Of course, you'd want to make sure that your sort was stable.

Comment: That is, if the contained objects are sortable...

Comment: This is `O(n log n)` on average. I think my method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042101/net-check-if-two-ienumerablet-have-the-same-elements/4044038#4044038) is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the inputs can contain duplicates you can't use Except. One algorithm is:

```
if the lists contain a different number of elements return false

make a copy of listA
foreach element in listB 
  if the element exists in copyA remove the first match from copyA
  otherwise return false
```

For an implementation you might look at the logic for the [.ShouldBeEqualTo() method](http://github.com/mvba/FluentAssert/blob/master/src/FluentAssert/AssertExtensions.cs#L58) in FluentAssert.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 return  l2.Count() == l1.Count() && l1.Intersect(l2).Count() == l2.Count();
```

You can also pass a custom comparer.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool HasElements(
        this IEnumerable<T> l1, 
        IEnumerable<T> l2,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparaer)
    {
        l2.Count() == l1.Count() && 
        return l1.Intersect(l2, comparer).Count() == l2.Count();
    } 
}
```

Comment: depends on which is the larger set...

Comment: Won't work. Enumerable.Intersect returns a *set*. new[]{2,2}.Intersect(new[]{2, 2}) returns {2}

Comment: It is just checking the count equals at first, this is so easy.

Comment: You really want to avoid walking the sequence twice if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
 public static bool HasSameElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target)
 {
     return (source.Count() == target.Count() && source.All(a => target.Contains(a)));
 }
```

Comment: You really want to avoid walking the sequence twice if you can.