# Check for any element that exists in two collections

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I'm wondering if Linq has a method to check if two collections have at least a single element in common. I would expect something like this:

```
var listA = new List<int>() { some numbers };
var listB = new List<int>() { some numbers, potentially also in list A };

bool hasSameElements = listA.hasMatchingElements(listB);
```

Does it exists in Linq or should I write a custom method for it?

I am aware of the Intersect method, but doesn't this yield the entire intersection set? I'm only interested in checking IF the two collection intersect, yielding the entire set seems like a waste, especially on larger collections.

Comment: `Intersect` only yields as many elements as it is asked for. If you follow it with `Any`, or `FirstOrDefault`, or do a `foreach` and break on the first iteration, it will only find the _first_ element that exists in both lists (if any) - it won't bother to find the rest.

Comment: Howver, note that the `Intersect` operation requires _one_ of the two sequences to be _completely_ read before the first element can be yielded. If one of your inputs is infinite, make sure it's not the input which is completely consumed. Note that [the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) for `Intersect` _lies_ about how it works.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Sounds like you just want:

```
bool hasSameElements = listA.Intersect(listB).Any();
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, `Intersect` uses lazy evaluation. It defers *all* execution until the first element is read from the result; at that point it will load *all* of `listB` into a set, and then stream `listA` until it finds a result to yield. At that point, `Any()` will return `true` and so no more work will be done. See my [Edulinq post on `Intersect`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling) for more information.

Comment: Doesn't this first yield the entire intersection set?

Comment: @Lews - not much help with `int`s, what if both lists contain a `0`?

Comment: @zeebonk No, it doesn't.  `Any` will stop as soon as a single item is returned (unless the entire set has no items) and Intersect uses deferred execution, so it will spit out each item as it comes across it.  This will be quite performant.

Comment: @zeebonk: Nope - see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling.aspx for details.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok tnx! Maybe add the comment of Servy to the answer? So the answer doesn't contain only the how but also the why?

Comment: @zeebonk: Added a bit more information than that. It's *somewhat* eager... but only on one sequence. (That may change whether you use `listA.Intersect(listB)` or `listB.Intersect(listA)` too.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Both the link in your post and the one in the comments are broken.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: will fix the post one when I get a chance. A search can probably find it for you before then.

Comment: Jon Skeet's post for lazy people: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling/
Too many pending edits, can't update it directly.