# Verify if two lists share values in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I'd like to know if two lists share values before applying an intersection. Something like *bool DoIntersect(listA, listB)* would be fabulous!

This is the code I came up with:

```
// Person is a class with Id and Name properties
List<Person> people1;
List<Person> people2;

// Populate people1 and people2...

// My current solution (pseudocode obviously)...

if (DoIntersect(people1, people2))
{
    people1 = people1.Intersect(people2)
}
else
{
    /* No shared people */
    throw exception;
}

// Continue with the process...
```

Comment: Define "share values". Do you mean "both lists contains the exact same people"?

Comment: I believe he meant have some common values (=Intersect) , you can get that from the required method 'Bool DoIntersect (..)'

Comment: Yes, people with the same Id. But, actually, I think there is a bug in my code. Let me test and make any corrections...

Comment: Yep, there was a bug in my code. The solution proposed by ChaseMedallion (**`a.Intersect(b).Any()`**) worked as needed. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check for any element that exists in two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584179/check-for-any-element-that-exists-in-two-collections)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want:

```
// are there any common values between a and b?
public static bool SharesAnyValueWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    return a.Intersect(b).Any();
}
```

For lists that don't overlap, this will iterate through a and b each once. For lists that overlap, this will iterate all the way through a, then through b until the first overlapping element is found.

```
// does a contain all of b? (ignores duplicates)
public static bool ContainsAllFrom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    return !b.Except(a).Any();
}
```

This will iterate through a once, then will iterate through b, stopping on the first element in b not in a.

```
// does a contain all of b? (considers duplicates)
public static bool ContainsAllFrom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    // get the count of each distinct element in a
    var counts = a.GroupBy(t => t).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    foreach (var t in b) {
        int count;
        // if t isn't in a or has too few occurrences return false. Otherwise, reduce
        // the count by 1
        if (!counts.TryGetValue(t, out count) || count == 0) { return false; }
        counts[t] = count - 1;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Similarly, this will iterate through a once, then will iterate through b, stopping on the first element in b not in a.

Answer (score 1):

I believe without altering the fact that you're using a List you can't get better performance.

However, if you would have **2 sorted lists** to begin with (requires overhead when creating them), then you could iterate through them with complexity of O(n) in order to find out if you have shared values.

**Edit:**

Although original OP doesn't have 2 sorted lists, in case someone will need it, here is the implementation for checking Intersection at O(n):

```
    public Boolean DoIntersect(SortedList<int,String> listA,SortedList<int,String> listB  )
    {
        if (listA == null || listA.Count == 0 || listB == null || listB.Count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var keysA = listA.Keys;
        var keysB = listB.Keys;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < listA.Count && j < listB.Count)
        {
            if (keysA[i] < keysB[j])
            {
                i++;
            }else if (keysA[i] > keysB[j])
            {
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

The above approach can be used also with IEnumerable lists, given that they are sorted, with slight variation - using GetEnumerator and iterating with it.

Comment: My lists are not sorted. Thanks for confirming my approach is fine. BTW when I get 15 as reputation I'll mark your answer as useful. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, keep in mind that you might want to keep them sorted if you plan on calling DoIntersect many times.on the other hand, if you have many inserts/deletes you might want to keep them non sorted. it very much depends on your usage for those lists.