# Difference between 2 sorted lists

Tags: c#

I have 2 sorted lists of strings with repetitions

```
ListA = {a,a,b,c,c,d,e,f}
ListB = {a,a,a,c,e,f,g,g}
```

If i pass this to some program like Diff or Compare It!, i would get the following output
 [image]

What i would like to have is the following lists

```
Listcommon = {a,a,c,e,f} (Common in both)

ListAdiff = {b,c,d} 

ListBdiff = {a,g,g}
```

Sorry if i was not clear before but this is what i want to do..Is there any in built classes in C# which can do this?
Or any other piece of code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for any element that exists in two collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584179/check-for-any-element-that-exists-in-two-collections)

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked many times, but you're looking for:

In both lists:

```
listA.Intersect(listB);
```

In A but not b:

```
listA.Except(listB);
```