# how to find members that exist in at least two lists in a list of lists

Tags: c#, list

I have an array of lists:

```
var stringLists = new List<string>[] 
{ 
    new List<string>(){ "a", "b", "c" },
    new List<string>(){ "d", "b", "c" },
    new List<string>(){ "a", "d", "c" }
};
```

I want to extract all elements that are common in at least 2 lists. So for this example, I should get all elements `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. I know how to find elements common to all but couldn't think of any way to solve this problem.

Comment: You can start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584179/check-for-any-element-that-exists-in-two-collections) and modify it to use a third collection.

Comment: You could use `SelectMany` to make a single list out of all your lists and then pick all elements with at least 2 occurances.

Comment: does duplicates possible in lists? i mean is list new List<string>(){ "a", "a", "a" } may occur?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
var result = stringLists.SelectMany(l => l.Distinct())
                        .GroupBy(e => e)
                        .Where(g => g.Count() >= 2)
                        .Select(g => g.Key);
```

---

Just for fun some iterative solutions:

```
var seen = new HashSet<string>();
var current = new HashSet<string>();
var result = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var list in stringLists)
{
    foreach(var element in list)
        if(current.Add(element) && !seen.Add(element))
            result.Add(element);

    current.Clear();
}
```

or:

```
var already_seen = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
foreach(var list in stringLists)
    foreach(var element in list.Distinct())
         already_seen[element] = already_seen.ContainsKey(element);

var result = already_seen.Where(kvp => kvp.Value).Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

or (inspired by [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31384417/142637)):

```
int tmp;
var items = new Dictionary<string,int>();

foreach(var str in stringLists.SelectMany(l => l.Distinct()))
{
    items.TryGetValue(str, out tmp);
    items[str] = tmp + 1;
}

var result = items.Where(kv => kv.Value >= 2).Select(kv => kv.Key);
```

Comment: gr8 anwer i tried two times but get it wrong both time ...this seems go working clean solution

Comment: Overlooked that it's so simple to count only occurence across lists, using `Distinct` is the key.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Dictionary<string, int>`, the key is the string and the value is the count:

```
Dictionary<string, int> itemCounts = new Dictionary<string,int>();
for(int i = 0; i < stringLists.Length; i++)
{
    List<string> list = stringLists[i];
    foreach(string str in list.Distinct())
    {
        if(itemCounts.ContainsKey(str))
           itemCounts[str] += 1;
        else
            itemCounts.Add(str, 1);
    }
}
var result = itemCounts.Where(kv => kv.Value >= 2);
```

I use `list.Distinct()` since you only want to count occurences in different lists.

As requested, here is an extension method which you can reuse with any type:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetItemsWhichOccurAtLeastIn<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> seq, int minCount, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    Dictionary<T, int> itemCounts = new Dictionary<T, int>(comparer);

    foreach (IEnumerable<T> subSeq in seq)
    {
        foreach (T x in subSeq.Distinct(comparer))
        {
            if (itemCounts.ContainsKey(x))
                itemCounts[x] += 1;
            else
                itemCounts.Add(x, 1);
        }
    }
    foreach(var kv in itemCounts.Where(kv => kv.Value >= minCount))
        yield return kv.Key;
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
string result = String.Join(",", stringLists.GetItemsWhichOccurAtLeastIn(2)); // a,b,c,d
```

Comment: I'd wrap this in a nice extensions method as well.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: as requested :)

Comment: Nice, but why a `for` loop instead of a second `foreach` loop?

Comment: @sloth: you're right, i could accept an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` instead of an `IList`. Index is not necessary due to `Distinct`. My first approach was taking care of the index to not count items in same collection twice. **Edited**

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a Dictionary element -> List of indices
2. loop over all lists
3. for list number i: foreach element in the list: add i to the list in the dictionary at position :  `dictionary[element].Add(i)` (if not already present)
4. Count how many lists in the dictionary have two entries

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the list and then pick all elemeents which occur twice or more:

```
var singleList = stringLists.SelectMany(p => p);
var results = singleList.Where(p => singleList.Count(q => p == q) >= 2).Distinct();
```

Comment: Awesome guys! Let's downvote the guy who posted his answer 30 seconds too late :-)