# Filter Object List by Property which is a integer list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like  below

```
 Class MyClass {

  string Name ;

  List<int>  scoreList;  //this contains integer values     

   }
```

I have a code to fill object list of above class type from database

```
List<MyClass> newList = //fill from db
```

I have a separate integer list having some numbers

```
List<int> filterList = new filterList();
```

Now I want to filter object list (newList) as any value(s) of property scoreList in filterList values

I wrote code like below but it seems to give incorrect results

```
 newList = newList .Where(x => x.scoreList.All(s => filterList .Contains(s))).ToList();
```

Can you help me to write a Linq query using c# to do above ?

Comment: Sorry, can you provide a sample output?  It might just be me, but your question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all items from newList where one or more of the scoreList values appears in filterList, then this should do it:

```
            newList = newList.Where(x => x.scoreList.Any(s => filterList.Contains(s))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newList = newList.Where(s=>s.ScoreList.Intersect(filterList).Any()).ToList();
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12584194/7607408 for more info on speed of this solution.

Comment: Given the comments in your link, it would seem to be better to implement the parts yourself: `var filterSet = new HashSet(filterList);` then you can filter using `Where(s => s.ScoreList.Any(sc => filterSet.Contains(sc)))` without the (implicit) overhead of building a `HashSet` over and over again.

Comment: True, but you brought up the topic of speed :)

Comment: Fair enough :-)